# How to set a background image in html/ASP.net that will work even when the site is moved?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm trying to set an image as a background image. From what I've read – I need to have a tilde (~) before the address or the site won't function if put inside a folder. But though that works when I do the following (which doesn't get the result I want because it's not a *background* image):

```
<asp:Image ID="MyImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Image1.png"/>
```

It doesn’t work in where I need it to work:

```
<body style="background-image: url(~/images/Image1.png) ; background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat">
```

Adding that tilde there causes the image to disappear.

So how do I add the tilde to a background image? (And why doesn't it work there?)

EDIT: I tried having just:

```
background-image: url(images/topleft.png)
```

(without the first forwardslash) but then any page inheriting from this page (which is a master page) didn't "find" the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are easier if you move all your styles into css, that way you don't have any problems resolving URLs because they're all relative to the location of your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple way in VWD to add a `style` for something in the stylesheet?

Comment: Css syntax is very similar to inline style syntax. Add a css stylesheet to your project and then write `body{ background-image:url(topleft.gif); background-position: top left;}`

Comment: Thanks. That worked (though I had to change it to:`url(../images/topleft.png)`). But it seems like there ought to be a simple way to do this with the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your css file in the root folder? May be your pages not finding css file or not same url for all the pages(pages that kept in different folder)? please make sure you have the correct directory structure:

```
+--Root folder

  +--Css (folder)
     \--Stylesheet.css

  +--Images (folder)
    \--image.jpg

  +--Pages (folder)
    \--mypage.aspx

 \--Default.aspx
```